# AppEngine Dev Server - Concurrent task limitation

Tags: java, google-app-engine, mapreduce

When I launch a mapreduce on app engine developement server using 8 workers, I can see that only 2 tasks are running in parallel instead of 8. 
Is there a way to bypass this limitation ?

Thanks.

Edit : When I launch dev server using command line, without providing java agent, I notice that only 1 task is run in parallel. When I provide java-agent in command line argument, I notice that 2 task are run in parallel. Therefore I assume that's app engine java-agent that manage how many thread are run on local server.,

Answer (score 2):

The Java development server as far I could figure out does not have thread limitations, while the Python development server is single-threaded so you can't truly run things in parallel.

Comment: If it is single-threaded then why do I see two (of my 8 cores) maxed when the map reduce is running? Is there any way to change that?

Comment: Yes, dev server is 2-threads safe whatever is defined in appengine-web.xml (even with <threadsafe>false</threadsafe>)

Comment: I am using app engine 1.6.5. and it does accept concurrent requests. I place a breakpoint at the start of the servlet code. Then I make two requests (from two different browsers). And I see that two different threads are handling the two different requests, and can step through them individually.